# Bootstrap accordion horizontal (inline-block) - collapse issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, horizontal-accordion

I have bootstrap accordion at the website, which is positioned horizontally (inline-block panels)

Bootply - [code](http://www.bootply.com/FBiufqozmD)

The problem occurs when I try to open text panel below the image, because all three other panels scroll to the bottom of accordion panel group. Example - [screenshot1](http://prntscr.com/bsq9qv) [screenshot2](http://prntscr.com/bsqa6j)...

Can you please help me how to fixed all panels to top when open any of panels body text?

When I change .panel-default style to position: absolute; All four panels appear over each other 
Live example here - http://www.twodotsmedia.com/u-izradi/uram-system/usluge.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following css:

```
.panel-default {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Its better to always use `vertical-align` property with `display: inline-block` explicitly.